# Cannot access Azure table with REST

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Have a table that is called "datatags" in the development server. I can access it using the StorageClient. However when I try to use the REST API I get ResourceNotFound error.

I tried with the following REST url

```
 http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/datatags
```

anyone know what the error could be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, since you didn't mention how you're setting all the right headers and signing the request, that you're trying to do an authenticated GET request. Table storage requires authentication on all requests.

In fact, I don't think that a GET against that URL is even defined. If you're trying to query entities, it would be something like `http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/datatags()`, but again, you'd need to set the right headers and sign the request.